# Superview isn't getting touch events

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a simple iPad app with the following layers of views:

- `BaseView` (covers the entire available area).
- `SquareView` (covers 100x100px area).

The `SquareView` is added as subview to `BaseView`.

I also have a `BaseViewController.m` file. In this file I added the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` functions to handle touch events. The problem is, when I click on the `SquareView` the touches functions get called, but when I click anywhere else they don't get called.

I have `userInteractionEnabled = YES` for the `SquareView`. I need this variable to be set in order to receive touches.

Clicking on the area outside the `SquareView` does not trigger the touches functions. I am puzzled as to why. Setting the `userInteractionEnabled` variable in the `BaseView` has no impact. What could be happening here? Is there some rule that I am missing? I am pretty sure I had it working at one point.

When the user clicks on the subview (`SquareView`) I need to launch a menu (let's say `MenuView` class). The idea is, when the user clicks on the area outside of the menu (or `SquareView`) I need to remove the pop-up `MenuView` by calling `[menuView removeFromSuperview]`. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: It's probably tough to find the right code to post for a question like this, but please try.  Good candidates are the creation and setup of the views.  Also NSLog(@"%@ %@", self.view, self.squareView) would be helpful.  My suspicion is that square view bounds are larger than you think they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use this code in your controller. It should work for you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [subview addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
     action:@selector(subviewTouched)]];
    [self.view addSubview:subview];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
     action:@selector(viewTouched)]];
}

- (void)viewTouched
{
    NSLog(@"viewTouched");
}

- (void)subviewTouched
{
    NSLog(@"subviewTouched");
}
```

Comment: What are the touchesBegin and touchesEnd functions for? Don't they achieve the same thing?

Comment: @user220201, you can use `touchesBegin` and `touchesEnd` methods to achieve the same thing. Though, usually they are used to recognize a unique gesture. They can give you more control over the touches than you actually need in most cases. So, if it's needed to handle a single touch then it's better to use a gesture recognizer for that. It's easier and faster this way.